# Why in MKDocs project this error ERROR Config value 'nav': Expected nav to be a list, got None Aborted with 1 Configuration Errors

Tags: yaml, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

this is the nav in my mkdocs.yml file.
Up to the User-Guides folder it all built perfectly. Then on adding the User Guides Tab and its md files to the list, got the error.

```
nav: 
    - index.md
    - Getting Started: 
      - 'Onboarding MH': 'EMD/getting-started/onboarding-ccm.md'
    - Operational Guides:
      - EMD/Operational-Guides/index.md
      - Setup and Installation:
          - 'Setting Up EMD On Edge': 'EMD/Operational-Guides/Setup-and-Installation/Setting-Up-EMD-On-Edge/setting-up-emd-on-edge.md'
      - Upgrading:
          - 'EMD 2.0 Upgrade': 'EMD/Operational-Guides/Upgrading/EMD-2.0-Upgrade.md'
      - Feature Flags:
          -  'Launch Darkly Flags': 'EMD/Operational-Guides/Feature-Flags/Launch-Darkly-Flags.md'
    - User Guides:
      - EMD/User-Guides/index.md
      - MH-Dictionary:
        - 'About': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/About.md'
        - Organization:
          - 'Organization': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Organization.md'
          - Business-Day:
            - 'Business-day-scheduler': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Business-Day/Business-day-scheduler.md'
          - Chain:
            - 'Stores': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Chain/Stores.md'
            - 'Touchpoints': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Chain/Touchpoints.md'
          - Culture:
            - 'Messages': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Culture/Messages.md'
          - General:
            - 'Reason Codes': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/General/Reason Codes.md'
          - Touchpoint Categories:
            - 'Touchpoint Applications': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Touchpoint Categories/Touchpoint Applications.md'
            - 'Touchpoint Groups': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Touchpoint Categories/Touchpoint Groups.md'
          - Touchpoint Devices:
            - 'Device Types': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Touchpoint Devices/Device Types.md'
            - 'Devices': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Organization/Touchpoint Devices/Devices.md'
        - Sales:
            - 'Sales': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Sales.md'
            - Barcodes:
              - 'Data Patterns': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Data Patterns.md'
              - 'General Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/General Tab.md'
              - Content Tab:
                - 'Blind Pickup Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Blind Pickup Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Cashier Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Cashier Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Content Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab.md'
                - 'Coupon Pickup Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Coupon Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Cradle Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Cradle Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Customer ALT and PIN Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Customer ALT and PIN Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Customer Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Customer Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Databar Item Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Databar Item Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Drivers License Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Drivers License Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'End Of Trip Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/End Of Trip Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Gift Receipt Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Gift Receipt Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'Group Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Group Data Pattern Type.md'
                - 'IMEI Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/IMEI Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Item Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Item Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Online Services Profile Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Online Services Profile Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Order Service Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Order Service Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Release Device Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Release Device Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Tax Exemption Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Tax Exemption Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Tender Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Tender Data Pattern Type.md' 
              - 'Transaction Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Transaction Data Pattern Type.md'
              - 'Warm Reboot Data Pattern Type': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Barcodes/Content Tab/Warm Reboot Data Pattern Type.md'
            - Items:
              - 'Online Purchase Profiles': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Items/Online Purchase Profiles.md'
              - 'PLU Groups': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Items/PLU Groups.md'
              - 'PLU Menus': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Items/PLU Menus.md'
            - Return Policies:
              - 'Details Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Return Policies/Details Tab.md'
              - 'Restrictions Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Return Policies/Restrictions Tab.md'
              - 'Return Policies': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Return Policies/Return Policies.md'
            - Rules:
              - 'Action Types': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Rules/Action Types.md'
              - 'Actions Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Rules/Actions Tab.md'
              - 'Age Restrictions': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Rules/Age Restrictions.md'     
              - 'Business Rule Types': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Rules/Business Rules Types.md'
              - 'Conditions Tab': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Rules/Conditions Tab.md'
            - Tax:
              - 'Tax Authorities': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax Authorities.md'
              - 'Tax Brackets': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax Brackets.md'
              - 'Tax Exemption Parameters': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax Exemption Parameters.md'     
              - 'Tax Rates': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax Rates.md'
              - 'Tax Zones': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax Zones.md'
              - 'Tax': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tax/Tax.md'
            - Tendering:
              - 'Currency Exchange Rates': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Currency Exchange Rates.md'
              - 'Currency': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Currency.md'
              - 'Donations': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Donations.md'     
              - 'Shopper ID Verification': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Shopper ID Verification.md'
              - 'Tender Exchange': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Tender Exchange.md'
              - 'Tender Fee Policy': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Tender Fee Policy.md'
              - 'Tender': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Tendering/Tender.md'
            - Touchpoint Behavior:
              - 'Branding': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Touchpoint Behavior/Branding.md'
              - 'Command Menu': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Touchpoint Behavior/Command Menu.md'
              - 'Tender Menu': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Touchpoint Behavior/Tender Menu.md'
              - 'Touchpoint Parameters': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/Touchpoint Behavior/Touchpoint Parameters.md'
            - US WIC Tendering:
              - 'WIC CVB Product Mapping': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/US WIC Tendering/WIC CVB Product Mapping.md'
              - 'WIC EBT Agencies': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/US WIC Tendering/WIC EBT Agencies.md'
              - 'WIC EBT Policy': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/US WIC Tendering/WIC EBT Policy.md'
              - 'WIC Product Exclusions': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Sales/US WIC Tendering/WIC Product Exclusions.md'
        - Appendix:
          - 'Browse or Lookup Item Selection': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Browse or Look Up Item Selection.md'
          - 'Group Search': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Group Search.md'
          - 'Location Search': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Location Search.md'
          - 'Product Search': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Product Search.md'
          - 'Search Function From All Screens': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Search Function From All Screens.md'
          - Create New Messages:
            - 'Create New Messages': 'EMD/User-Guides/MH-Dictionary/Appendix/Create New Messages/Create New Messages.md'
      - MH-Configuration:
```

I tried additional indents, I double checked spacing, double-checked quotations.

Comment: Is your repo open? If yes, could you put the link in the description? It is difficult to read the `nav` section inside your `mkdocs.yml` and the link to the repo could make it easier to reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.